# ¿Será posible evitar respuestas anticipadas a preguntas mal formuladas?

Tags: discusión

No solo me gusta este sitio, ha sido por mucho tiempo (su versión en inglés) mi primera opción de búsqueda ante mis dudas de desarrollo, es por eso que me tome en serio la participación en este lugar y me gustaría preocuparme más por su constante mejora.

Al grano: Bajo mi percepción, responder preguntas de mala calidad, antes que estas sean editadas, o mejoradas o cerradas no ayudan al objetivo del sitio ya que muchas preguntas de este tipo quedan con respuestas válidas pero que solo le sirven a quien las formuló.

He visto muchas preguntas incluso que llegan a tener votos negativos y que ya tienen respuesta a los 2 minutos de formulada.

De ahí mi pregunta ¿Será posible establecer un mejor criterio, al menos de los usuarios con más reputación o más antiguos, al responder las preguntas de mala calidad?

Quizás esperar la re edición, una mejor formulación etc. Solo apelo al criterio no hablo de penalizar ni nada de eso. ¿Les parece interesante discutir sobre esto?

Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el problema de este planteo es que te enfocas en las preguntas, cuando la mayoría de los que llegan aquí (o eventualmente lleguen) lo hacen en busca de respuestas.

Por ello, no hay que evitar responder, hay que **Responder** y **Editar**. Si! tu respóndela y luego edita la pregunta para hacerla mejor y fácil de hallar en google, ¿por que no?

Fíjate que hace poco mas de un año Stack Exchange estreno una nueva familia de medallas: **Explicador**, **Refinador** e **Iluminador**.

El argumento ([en este post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-%E2%86%92refiner-%E2%86%92-illuminator)) de su incorporación es básicamente que frente a una buena respuesta a una mala pregunta, es fácil para un entendido en el tema, editar la pregunta para que sea util y *encontrable* por otros usuarios. Y no digo que todas las respuestas a malas preguntas sean buenas, muchas no lo son, para ellas están los votos.

Dice algo así: (traducción libre)

> Esto no sólo se aplica a preguntas -pobres o casi pobres- a veces una buena edición significa la diferencia entre que 100 y 10.000 personas puedan encontrar algo a través de buscar en Google. Los buenos títulos son difíciles.

y

> Es fácil, para un entendido, convertir una mala pregunta en una pregunta que ayude a mucha gente

Estas medallas intentan motivarnos a responder preguntas que en principio parecen malas, pero que en el fondo plantean un problema que pueden tener muchas otras personas en el futuro.

Así que, parece bien responder una mala pregunta si te tomas el trabajo de editarla para hacerla mas *encontrable* y compresible, pero sobre todo que se enfoque en el *problema real* mas allá del planteo del usuario. Muchos no saben cual es el problema tienen en realidad... si tienes éxito en esto habrás hecho tu aporte para la posteridad.

Comment: No entiendo cómo puedes editar preguntas que dicen *Tengo que hacer foo. ¿Alguien puede hacerlo por mí porque soy demasiado holgazán para hacerlo? No entraré más al sitio hasta ver cómo se han peleado por responder esta pregunta y ganar reputación* y hay gente que buenamente escribe comentarios para que se mejore la calidad de **la pregunta** pero luego viene un vampiro de reputación y solo publica una respuesta que probablemente es sacada de uno (o más) tutoriales en internet haciendo de SOes un blog más que un sitio de preguntas y respuestas...

Comment: Para mí, desde la pregunta hasta la respuesta deberían ser cerradas y eliminadas: la pregunta por ser de mala calidad y la respuesta porque apoya a la contaminación del sitio.

Comment: jajaj. radical, pero no es la idea, aveces alguien pregunta una burrada, y tu sabes que esa burrada puede ser editada para que tenga sentido por que es posible dar una buena respuesta que sea util para otros.

Comment: Muy de acuerdo con @LuiggiMendoza.