# ¿Cual sería el modo apropiado de lidiar con una pregunta del estilo "es esto posible"?

Tags: discusión

Buenas,

En ocasiones me encuentro con preguntas que si bien parecen *on-topic*, podrían no serlo.

Este tipo de preguntas tienen un esquema parecido al siguiente:

> Hola, he estado intentando hacer _____ en _____ tecnología/lenguaje
>   pero no lo he conseguido. ¿Es esto posible o estoy perdiendo el
>   tiempo?

¿Que se debería hacer con ese tipo de preguntas? A mi modo de ver hay una serie de caminos de actuación:

1. Realizar un comentario sobre la factibilidad de la pregunta (en
   positivo o negativo) intentando referenciar un artículo o
   documentación sobre ese tema si lo hubiera.
2. Idem al punto 1 pero en una respuesta.
3. En el caso de conocer si es posible o no, responder con una solución
   o ejemplo donde se puede hacer lo que se pregunta.
4. Rechazar, cerrar o reportar la pregunta por ser *off-topic*

Quizás ya no sólo es cuál sería el modo más correcto de responder a esa pregunta si no cuál sería el modo más *StackOverflow way* o mejor dicho cuál sería el procedimiento que se **quisiera** usar en StackOverflow en español para tratar esa pregunta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En el caso específico de las preguntas "es posible hacer", lo primero que hago es parafrasear mentalmente la pregunta de algo como

> Hola, he estado intentando hacer _____ en _____ tecnología/lenguaje pero no lo he conseguido. ¿Es esto posible o estoy perdiendo el tiempo?

a

> ¿Cómo puedo hacer [X] en [Y] tecnología/lenguaje?

Luego sigo la orientación básica que está en [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

> **Contesta preguntas [bien formadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**
>
> No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar. Ahórrate un
>   poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que…
>
> - ... son inciertas o deficientes en detalles específicos que puedan identificar el problema real.
> - ...solicitan [opiniones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) en vez de realidades.
> - ...ya se han preguntado antes y se han contestado varias veces.
> - ...requieren demasiada dirección para que puedas contestarla completamente.
> - ...no tratan sobre la programación o el desarrollo [como lo definimos en el Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
>
> No se te olvide que [puedes editar la pregunta que estas contestando](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)
>   para mejorar la claridad y el enfoque - esto puede reducir la
>   probabilidad de que tu pregunta sea [cerrada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) o [removida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions).

Dependiendo del caso específico, pues

- Decido si votar +1 / -1 u omito votar
- y comento, si aplica
- y respondo, si aplica
- y/o comento en el chat, cuando es algo interesante
- y/o pregunto en Meta, cuando es algo interesante

Por cierto, en la sección "Preguntas Relacionadas" del panel derecho se incluye:

- [¿Será posible evitar respuestas anticipadas a preguntas mal formuladas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/485/65)

Una pregunta similar, casi simultánea

- [¿Que hacer cuando respuesta es la solución de una pregunta pero fomenta a los usuarios a hacer preguntas que no cumplen con las reglas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1893/65)

Comment: He estado esperando por alguien tenía otro punto de vista que reflejar. Siendo que ese no ha sido el caso te dejo aquí un comentario. La respuesta que ofreces si bien más que correcta, está sujeta a mucha interpretación y al fin y al cabo se trata a la pregunta como si fuera una pregunta cualesquiera (lo cual también tiene sentido). No tengo claro si estoy del todo de acuerdo con ello pero al menos me has resuelto las dudas que tenía, lo resumo en: "Se trata como si de otra pregunta cualquiera fuera, se le aplican los mismos criterios tanto objetivos como subjetivos".

Comment: @frikinside: A mí también me gustaría leer respuestas de otros miembros de la comunidad. Sé que algunos andan con mucho trabajo así que no he perdido "las esperanzas". Considera invitar a los usuarios del [chat] a que te den su punto de vista.

Answer (score 2):

Usualmente los pasos que sigo en este tipo de preguntas son los siguientes:

- *Leer mas de una vez la pregunta:* **A veces**, el OP no es bueno expresando su problema y puede que la pregunta tenga valor en el sitio; solo es cuestión de editar la pregunta.
- *En caso de que la pregunta tenga valor*: **voto positivo + comentario de bienvenida**:

> **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
>   **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes
>   [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc.
>   Hasta que no añadas mas información, me temo que tu pregunta quedará
>   [en espera-¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en
>   espera"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), pero si
>   editas tu pregunta y la mejoras, la comunidad puede optar por abrirla
>   y darte una solución. Saludos.

- *En caso de que la pregunta NO posea algún valor para el sitio:* **Voto negativo** "usualmente si el OP conoce del sitio, pero no sigue la guía de **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**" o el OP es nuevo y al pasar 1 hora mas o menos el OP no brinda mas información; además de **agregar un comentario así**:

> **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
>   **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes
>   [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc.
>   Hasta que no añadas mas información, me temo que tu pregunta quedará
>   [en espera-¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en
>   espera"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), pero si
>   editas tu pregunta y la mejoras, la comunidad puede optar por abrirla
>   y darte una solución. Saludos.

- *Si la pregunta no se puede salvar*: **voto negativo + comentario *"mas asertivo"* + reportar para su cierre** (baja calidad, por ejemplo).

> [Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en
>   Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Este portal no se ha
>   creado para hacerle la tarea a nadie sino para resolver dudas
>   concretas. **[edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado.
>   Hasta que no añadas mas información, tu pregunta quedará [en
>   espera-¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en
>   espera"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).